# ActionScript: Can I start learning ActionScript directly from As3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I need to learn ActionScript. I have no basic knowledge on ActionScript. Can I directly start learning ActionScript3 or I have to start with ActionScript1. please guide me along with some tutorials.
Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. There are a number of tutorials/books on AS3. Please google for them. [AS3 Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526955) and [Programming AS3 from Adobe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_as3_programming.pdf) are two good resources on AS3.

Answer (score 2):

ActionScript 1 and ActionScript 2 are rather unrelated and obsolete languages for Flash Player. If you're targeting Flash Player >= 9 (I suppose so) the knowledge of AS1 and AS2 can confuse you.

So you can learn AS3 from scratch without any knowledge of AS1 and AS2. It is the most preferable way for now.

Answer (score 2):

You can learn AS3 directly.

this is a good website that I have used for tutorials

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/

Answer (score 1):

it's actually better to start with learning ActionScript 3.0 since it's quite different than ActionScript 2.0 in many aspects not knowing it you won't have to *unlearn* all that has changed.

they are practically different languages.